# missing arguments for method apply in object List; Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use code for a school assignment, and I copied the professors outline like we were supposed to but one of the lines is causing an error in my ide saying missing arguments for method apply in object List; the line of code is

```
private var d = List[(String,Any)]
```

and I really don't understand what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 7):

You need parens after the type to actually create the empty list:

```
private var d = List[(String,Any)]()
```

or alternatively:

```
private var d = List.empty[(String,Any)]
```

Comment: Sorry that is from me messing around with it, the extra parenthesis shouldn't have been there I was getting an error when it wasnt.